# VBA MS Access Open Report in "Report View"

Tags: ms-access, report, vba

Is there a command to open a report via VBA - currently I've used the docmd acViewPreview but this doesn't really solve the problem as the print preview does not give you a very good view of the report on your computer. What I need is the "Report View", just as one would do if they "double clicked" the report from the navigation pane.

It seems like this should be super easy, appologies, I'm used to working with forms more than reports.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptYourName", acViewReport
```

Comment: This works Thank you! - simple simple.  & @user2497624 - thank you also

Answer (score 2):

DoCmd.OpenReport "name_of_your_report", A_PREVIEW

Comment: That is equivalent to acViewPreview, which the OP is already using.

Comment: Yeah sorry, long day at work working on forms in MS Access, wrote it mechanically. use acViewReport instead of A_PREVIEW